# For Loop through Ajax OnChange not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop

I am trying to loop the OnChange method through AJAX call but surprisingly it won't work.

```
for (let index = 0; index < 300; index++) {
        $('#txtLini'+[index]).on('change', function() {
            var lini=this.value;
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?=base_url()?>index.php/fin/controller/M_index/getKode',
                method: 'post',
                data: {lini: lini},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                $.each(response,function(index,data){
                    console.log(index);
                    document.getElementById("txt_sumberdaya"+[index]).value = data['TEXT'];
                });
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

In my javascript above, I'm trying to loop my `textbox` id to process in ajax call. I have many ids `(txtLini0,txtLini1,txtLini2,etc.)` and many possibilities too in each id user want to choose. Therefore I use id to be a particular variable in `OnChange` method. What user type in each id can affect in another `id (txt_sumberdaya0, txt_sumberdaya1, txt_sumberdaya2, etc.)` with output in `Onchange` Ajax.

I've tried to loop just like this but it won't work as I want.
For example:

If user type in id `txtLini0` the output from ajax should be filled in `txt_sumberdaya0`. and so on.

But in here my error was when I tried to fill id `txtLini1` or `txtLini2` the output from ajax still going filled in `txt_sumberdaya0`. It seems my index loop still going on 0 every come to ajax success process.

Is there anyone who can fix my code or any other ideas to make it clear?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below approach using classes to bind an `onChange` event. What you're doing in AJAX response is wrong. there you don't need any loop.

```js
$('.txtLini', document).each(function(index, item) {
  $(item).on('change', function() {
    var lini = this.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + (index + 1),
      method: 'get',
      // data: {
      //   lini: lini
      //  },
      //  dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
       // console.log($('#txt_sumberdaya' + (index + 1)));
        $('#txt_sumberdaya' + (index + 1)).val(JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    });
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  INput : <input type="text" id="txtLini1" class="txtLini" /> Copy input : <input type="text" id="txt_sumberdaya1" class="txt_sumberdaya" />
</div>

<div>
  INput : <input type="text" id="txtLini2" class="txtLini" /> Copy input : <input type="text" id="txt_sumberdaya2" class="txt_sumberdaya" />
</div>

<div>
  INput : <input type="text" id="txtLini3" class="txtLini" /> Copy input : <input type="text" id="txt_sumberdaya3" class="txt_sumberdaya" />
</div>

<div>
  INput : <input type="text" id="txtLini4" class="txtLini" /> Copy input : <input type="text" id="txt_sumberdaya4" class="txt_sumberdaya" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the advice @shyammakwana.me but how to pass the variable that user input to URL? I just sending 1,2,3 in that URL.

Comment: what's in your variable? a text from an input ? if yes then you can get text input by `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation.  When an event happens in Javascript it "bubbles up" to parent elements.  This means that if you have:

```
<div id="foo"><!-- lots of inputs --></div>
```

You can use a single event listener for all of them:

```
$('#foo').on('change', 'input', (e) => // ...
```

But how do you know which input triggered the event?  That `e` argument will have both `target` and `currentTarget` properties, which give you both the element you attached the event handler to, and the element that triggered the event.

By using those event properties you should get the correct index for the input that triggered the event.  Alternatively, you can also avoid using `=>` functions, and in that case you can just use `this` to refer to the `input`.

For more info see: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Thanks to @machineghost for the advice but I still confuse how to implement a single event listener as you mentioned for my case above.

Comment: Right now you have `$('#txtLini'+[index]).on('change'`.  Change that to ` $('#parentElement').on('change', 'input'`.  The latter says "listen for all change events that happen on input events inside #parentElement".

Answer (score -1):

after looking at your code again the reason you are getting the 0 is because the index passed in your `each`           `$.each(res,function(index,data)`the index value will depend on the length of the data in your array response so if it's 1 the `index` of the foreach loop will always default to `0` to fix this is simple change the name from `index` to for ex `i` `$.each(res,function(i,data)`
or if you are not using it remove it and pass index directley of the outer loop

your final code should look like this

```
for (let index = 0; index < 300; index++) {
        $('#txtLini'+[index]).on('change', function() {
            var lini=this.value;
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?=base_url()?>index.php/fin/controller/M_index/getKode',
                method: 'post',
                data: {lini: lini},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                $.each(response,function(data){
                    console.log(index);   // the index you will get here is the index of the outer loop
                    document.getElementById("txt_sumberdaya"+[index]).value = data['TEXT'];
                });
                }
            });
        });
    }
```